# calculating Sun's J band mag via integrating the Planck’s law

Tags: mathematics, python, photometry, black-body, filter

```
T=5772  # surface temperature of the sun
r1=1 # unit: in solar radius

r2=r1*(6.957e8)       # unit: radius in meter
k = 1.381e-23         # Boltzmann
h = 6.626e-34         # Planck
c = 3e8               # light speed
d = 3.086e17          # 10pc, in meter, absolute magnitude

def pk(t, l): # l: wavelength in meter
    x = (h*c)/(k*t*l)
    c1 = 8*(np.pi)*h*(c**2)/(l**5)   #l: wavelength in meter
    p1 = c1 / (np.exp(x)-1)          #   j/s/m2/m
    p2=(1e-7)*p1                     #   erg/s/cm2/angstron
    return(p2)


eff = np.genfromtxt('2MASS_2MASS.J.dat', comments='#')  #[1]
a1,b1=eff[:,0],eff[:,1]  # lambda and its transmission; Suppose dat's lambda has a step of 1 Angstron


bbf=[] #wavelength--> Planck 
for i in np.arange(a1[0],a1[-1]+1): #i in Angstron
    j=i*(1e-10) #j in meter
    bbf=bbf+[pk(T,j)]  #j in meter
    
f1,f2=sum([o*p*q for o,p,q in zip(bbf,a1,b1)]),sum([p*q for p,q in zip(a1,b1)])
mag=-2.5*np.log10(f1/f2/r2*r2/d/d)-23.75 #A11 of [2]
print("J mag:",mag)
```

Sun's absolute Vega magnitude in the J band is about 3.67 mag.
The code above presents a very deviate result. **So where is the mistake?**

The sun should NOT have a large deviation in the J band.

1. http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/getdata.php?format=ascii&id=2MASS/2MASS.J
2. https://doi.org/10.1086/664083

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you are putting the integrated flux onto a magnitude system?

Comment: That is the original definition of magnitude.  See  reference 1 or https://www.stsci.edu/hst/instrumentation/acs/data-analysis/zeropoints  .The integration is based on A(11) of reference 1.  When bin size is small enough, summation can replace integration. The bin size is 1 Angstron.

Comment: @ProfRob   Are there any errors in the formula or the code?